# Creating specific a-entities (lines) in JS

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to create multiple lines in javascript to include into an a-scene.

It works this way for creating primitives but there is no "a-line"-primitive.

```
      AFRAME.registerComponent('lines', {
        schema: {},
        multiple: true,
        init: function () {
          var n = 2;
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
            var entityEl = document.createElement('a-entity');
            var posit = {x: i, y: 0.1, z: -3};
            entityEl.setAttribute('position', posit);
            // I also tried: entityLi.setAttribute('line', '');
            entityLi.setAttribute('geometry', 'primitive:line');
            entityEl.setAttribute('color', "#03ef3e");
            sceneEl.appendChild(entityEl);  
            }
        }
      });
```

Is there a possibility to create lines without first defining a new primitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`line`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/line.html#sidebar) component:

```
<a-entity line='start: 0 0 0; end: 1 1 1; color: red'></a-entity>
```

You can set the `start` and `end` in javascript to update the line:

```
element.setAttribute('line', {
   'start': '0 0 0',
   'end': newPosVector
}
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yg083sz2/2/).